How to narrow the signature within a function based on the value of an argument?
Im trying to combine the methods of an interface into a single function with an additional operation parameter. The resulting function can be called as expected, but it seems I can't get the signature to narrow within the function. This SO question was somewhat helpful but the compiler still thinks args[1] can be undefined within the "plus" case:
interface Calculator {
    plus: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    unaryPlus: (a: number) => number;
}

type CalculateParameters = {
    [P in keyof Calculator]: [P, ...Parameters<Calculator[P]>];
}[keyof Calculator];

const calculate = (...[operation, ...args]: CalculateParameters) => {
    switch (operation) {
        case "plus":
            // Object is possibly undefined
            return args[0] + args[1];
        case "unaryPlus":
            return args[0];
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown operation.");
    }
};

// Work as expected
export const x = calculate("plus", 1, 2);
export const y = calculate("unaryPlus", 1);

Playground
I experimented with conditional types as suggested here but that requires a lot of duplication as well as casting. Is it possible to narrow the signature within calculate without that?
P.S. Once the argument typing problem is solved, I'm also facing the problem of typing the return value correctly. Calculator could have functions that return something else than number and calculate should be able to reflect that.

You can go with:
interface Calculator {
    plus: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    unaryPlus: (a: number) => number;
}

type CalculateParameters = {
    [P in keyof Calculator]: [P, ...Parameters<Calculator[P]>];
}[keyof Calculator];

const calculate = (...args: CalculateParameters) => {
    switch (args[0]) {
        case "plus":
            // Object is possibly undefined
            return args[1] + args[2];
        case "unaryPlus":
            return args[1];
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown operation.");
    }
};

// Work as expected
export const x = calculate("plus", 1, 2);
export const y = calculate("unaryPlus", 1);

See How to infer/narrow-down a function parameter type based on the narrowed-down type of another function parameter? for a detailed discussion

Thanks, that works (assuming the indices in the implementation are incremented)! Do you have any suggestion on how to declare the return type of calculate, see P.S. in question?
